# How to access IAM user and assigned policies from Athena table

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have created a s3 bucket and uploaded JSON file for AWS IAM user and permissions file. Now I want to create a table in Athena and from this table I want read the IAM user list and permissions or policies attached to IAM user from Athena.

Comment: What is your actual question? What do you mean by "the iam user list"? Is this a table you are creating in Athena, or are you referring to actual IAM Users defined in AWS? Could you possibly edit your question to define what you are doing in several, smaller steps? Also, please tell us what problems you are actually having.

Comment: I have pulled the report for all Iam users list with their attached policies in jason formate . So needs get the user list and permissions report from athena.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking. Amazon Athena can be used to query data that is stored in Amazon S3, such as CSV files or complex formats. What data do you have stored in Amazon S3 and what difficulties are you having querying it? What has IAM got to do with Athena? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: I have downloaded Iam list of users with permissions attached to iam users. That out file is json file and i have uploaded in s3 bucket. Now i want create one athena database db and table having Iam users permissions. Now i want run the query for jason file and expecting athena query output need shows what are policies atyached to users. If you need more information lete know.

Comment: Ah! Okay. You will need to write a `CREATE TABLE` statement that describes the format of the input files. That will be quite a challenge! This article on a similar topic might help: [Create Tables in Amazon Athena from Nested JSON and Mappings Using JSONSerDe | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/)

Comment: Can you post a sample json file that you want to query if you still didn't find solution to your problem

Comment: sorry for delayed response I'm attaching sample Jason file please suggest.

Comment: I'm not able attach the file pls let me know how i can share